# NSMutableDictionary in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have `NSMutableArray` populated with `NSMutableDictionary` objects, how can I retrieve let's say second item in `NSMutableArray` and change that dictionary.

```
NSMutableArray *tempArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary *al = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for(int i=0; i<[theArray count]; i++) {
    id object = [theArray objectAtIndex: i];
    id object2 = @"0";
    [al  setObject:object forKey:@"titles"];
    [al setObject:object2 forKey:@"levels"];
    [tempArr addObject:al];
}


NSLog(@"fubar %@", [tempArr objectAtIndex:2]);
```

So i need to access NSDictionary by Key and change Key's value. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in an array are, as you have discovered, accessed using the `-objectAtIndex:` method on `NSArray`.

Similarly, objects in a dictionary are accesses using `-objectForKey:` on `NSDictionary`.

To do what you want, just stack the accesses as with any other call, like so:

```
NSLog(@"fubar %@", [[tempArr objectAtIndex:2] objectForKey:@"titles"]);
```

Take note, the indexing on `NSArray` starts at 0, not 1.

To change values, the same principle applies:

```
[[tmpArr objectAtIndex:2] setObject:titlesArray forKey:@"titles"];
```

Comment: How to find the index which is "2" in this example of the found dictionary in the array?

Comment: @Ron I'm not quite sure what you mean; `-indexOfObject:`, maybe?

Comment: I have a dictionary with a specific key and value. This dictionary is inside an NSMutableArray. I want to update the dictionary with a specific key and this dictionary is at a certain index inside the array. I want to find the index of this dictionary object. Currently, my dictionary is at index 0 and my indexpath is 1, so 'indexpath.row' doesn't help me. Does that make sense to you? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a value in a `NSMutableDictionary` store in an `NSMutableArray`, use this code:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1",@"key1",nil],[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value2",@"key2",nil], nil];

//Edit second value
NSMutableDictionary *dict = (NSMutableDictionary *)[array objectAtIndex:1];
[dict setObject:@"value3" forKey:@"key2"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDicts = (NSMutableDictionary *)[yourArray objectAtIndex:yourIndex];
// Change your tempDicts 
[tempDicts setObject:@"" forKey:@""];
```

and Finally

```
[yourArray insertOjbect:tempDicts atIndex:yourIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is an instance variable (called `_array`):

```
- (void)setObject:(id)value
           forKey:(id)key
          atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if (index >= [_array count]) {
        NSLog(@"Index %ld out-of-range", index);
        return;
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [_array objectAtIndex:index];
    [dict setObject:value forKey:key];
}
```

To use:

```
[self setObject:@"foobar" forKey:@"title" atIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for(dict in tempArr)
    {

       //you can access dictionay here and set the value 
    }
```